# Linear Model Loops

Tags: r

I am running a univariate analysis on how various baseline characteristics impact a complication. Here is a snippet of where I look individual characteristic `SEX`, `BMI` and `AGE` and how they individually impact `COMPLICATION`.

What I would like to do is to have this also cycle through complications like

```
COMPLICATION1
COMPLICATION2
COMPLICATION3
```

Here is the sample code I have

```
#Generate list of predictors for univariate logistic model
varlist <- c(“SEX",
             “BMI”,
             ”AGE")

#Run univariate logistic model based on predictors using "COMPLICATION" as an outcome
lapply(varlist, function(x) {
  mod <- glm(reformulate(x, 'COMPLICATION'), 
             data = NSQIP_D.clean, 
             family = binomial)
  summary.glm(mod)$coefficients
}) -> results

#Combine Model results into one file
results <- do.call(rbind, results)

#Write table of results
write.table(results, file="Univariate_Results.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
require("tidyverse")

lapply(c("COMPLICATION1", "COMPLICATION2", "COMPLICATION3"), function(y) {
  lapply(c("SEX", "BMI", "AGE"), function(x) {
    glm(paste0(y, " ~ ", x), data = NSQIP_D.clean, family = binomial) %>% 
      summary() %>% 
      .$coefficients %>% 
      return() 
    }) %>% 
    do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
    cbind(y, .) %>% 
    return()
}) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  write.table(file = "Univariate_Results.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = T)
```

Here you run the three univariate regressions for each complication and store the results in a joint text file. I wrote this in tidyverse syntax. However, you could also express that using base R.

Comment: That’s great thank you. Only thing I changed was made new variables complist and predilist to put complications and predictor variables in just for cleaner formatting.

Comment: If you’re listening. Any chance to the complication in listed in the rows somewhere in the output? Right now its just has output SEX/BMI/AGE that repeats for each complication but the complication is not listed in printout so it’s hard to know what each output is corresponding to. I can also post this as a separate question.

Comment: I added the line `cbind(y, .) %>%` to the code. That lists the dependent variable in the output.